# Div with a width of 100%, next to a fixed width one

Tags: css, sharepoint, html, width

Sorry for the incredibly stupid question, I feel like in most circumstances I could do this easily, but I'm using sharepoint at the moment and trying to do anything in this is hell!

Basically I have a side navigation (.menu-vertical) that is 230px wide, and a div next to it (.mainContent) that I would like to (padding aside!) fill the rest of the screen.

Unfortunately there are around 798 randomly placed divs, spans and whatever else in the code too that I can't seem to strip without breaking the site, so any advice on exactly how to achieve this would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I was ready to answer your question until I read the last paragraph. Nobody can really help you with that..

Comment: Just try what you suggested in the title- give it `width: 100%`?  Maybe you need to wrap them both in a container div and float them?  Or maybe just float them with `width:100%`?

Comment: @thirtydot - unfortuantely there doesn't seem to be any way around this with Sharepoint, although the basis of the site is in place with a .container div, and the .menu-vertical (fixed) and .mainContent (fluid, 100%) divs inside.

Comment: @jtfairbank - many thanks, but I do already have the container div at 100%, and the side menu that is 230px, but what attribute do I then give the main content area? Width 100% makes it the same width as the container. Thanks again.

Comment: Wish I had enough rep to offer a bounty :D

Comment: A bounty wouldn't help with the fundamentally unanswerable part that is your last paragraph. I'm just going to pretend it doesn't exist and answer anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Basically I have a side navigation (.menu-vertical) that is 230px
>   wide, and a div next to it (.mainContent) that I would like to
>   (padding aside!) fill the rest of the screen.
>
> ..
>
> the basis of the site is in place with a .container div, and the
>   .menu-vertical (fixed) and .mainContent (fluid, 100%) divs inside.

From what I understand, you're looking for this: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/wv42t/

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    border: 3px solid #666;
    overflow: hidden
}
.menu-vertical {
    width: 230px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #f0f
}
.mainContent {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 30px;
    border: 2px solid #00f
}
```

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="menu-vertical">menu-vertical</div>
    <div class="mainContent">mainContent</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This actually works, perfectly - thank you! I was playing around with the code until late last night and came up with something similar, but this is great and very simple, love the solution! Thanks again