# div 100% width with other div fixed

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a css layout for all modern browsers going and having a hard time. I am not a css guru but hoping one could guide me in the right direction. I'm trying to get a layout similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666880/div-with-a-width-of-100-next-to-a-fixed-width-one) but with a 100% height left nav and 100% width for the rest. see below layout image.

[image]

Based on the link above, I have this, but missing the 100% height...

```
    .wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        border: 3px solid #666;
        overflow: hidden
    }

    .menu-vertical {
        width: 230px;
        float: left;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 2px solid #f0f
    }

    .mainContent {
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 2px solid #00f
    }
    .banner {
        background-color: red;
        height: 50px;
    }
    .contentBox {
        background-color: pink;
        height: 200px;
        margin: 20px;
    }


<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="menu-vertical">side</div>
    <div class="mainContent">
        <div class="banner">banner</div>
        <div class="contentBox">content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated, thank-you

Comment: This is one of those questions that has been asked many times in many variations. Grab one of the existing examples and see what you can make of it, then ask for help with more specific problems.

Comment: @Nathan Lee, I've updated my question showing what I have so far. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div style="height:100%;position:absolute; width:10%; margin:0; top:0; left:0;  background-color:red;">Content</div>
<div style="height:10%; position:absolute;width:90%; margin:0; top:0; left:10%;background-color:blue;">Content</div>
<div style="height:90%;position:absolute; width:90%; margin:0; top:10%; left:10%; background-color:yellow;margin:0 auto;"><div style="background-color:green;width:95%;height:95%;position:relative;top:20px;left:30px;">Content</div></div>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: try this out, its exactly what you want, just change the values if you want... @Thibs

Comment: Thank-you. very close, but the green section is clipping and there are scroll bars. Green section should not clip like my image. This was one issue I could not fix before.

Comment: sorry? could you please re-word your comment? @Thibs

Comment: The green section should be a square, right now it expands to the bottom and right side of browser. thanks

Comment: @Thibs and as i said, you can always use the same code and change the values